# pass mpi rank to bash script through system() C/C+ ; bizzare error

Tags: c, linux, bash, mpi, system-calls

I have an C, with MPI, code that should takes should execute a bash script in different directories depending on the mpi-rank. For example: If I run this with mpirun -np 10 mycode.o It should each process should execute the call system(s) where s is a string created from snprintf(s, sizeof(s), "/home/myaccount/myscript.sh %d", rank);

The full code is below:

```
#include        <stdio.h>
#include        <mpi.h>          /* MPI header file */ 
#include        <stdlib.h>
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {

   int rank, size;
                             /* init into MPI */
   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
                             /* my rank - my id */
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
                             /* how many processes in the virtual machine */
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);


                             /*create script input (convert rank to string)*/
  char s[256];
  snprintf(s, sizeof(s), "/home/myaccount/myscript.sh %d", rank);
                             /* run script */
  system(s);


                             /* out of the virtual machine */
  MPI_Finalize();

  }
```

And a test script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
for((k=16;k<22;k+=2));
    do echo cd /otherdirectory/test/"$k"/"$1"/;
    done;
exit;
```

which when I run with mpirun -np 10 should give:

cd /otherdirectory/test/16/0/
cd /otherdirectory/test/16/9/
cd /otherdirectory/test/16/8/

And so on. But instead returns

cd /otherdirectory/test/16/is_csh/
cd /otherdirectory/test/18/is_csh/
cd /otherdirectory/test/20/is_csh/

And I can't figure-out where the "is_csh" is coming from. If I use printf("%s\n") instead of system(s), I do get what I expect above.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you see if you make the script just do `echo "$@"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You output `$k` after /test/. $k runs from 16 to 20. So this is what you should expect.

I would assume that you have a .bashrc in your home directory, or maybe a /etc/bashrc, which trashes $1, so when your script is finally reached, the argument was overwritten by something else.

Or maybe your system shell is csh or tcsh or something similar, and you switch to bash after logging in. When you start your script from the command line, bash executes it directly. But the system() call will get your shell from /etc/passwd and run `<shell> -c <args to system>`, so a .login or .cshrc or similar file that gets executed by csh on startup might be the culprit as well.

Comment: Check your `.bashrc` for something like `set is_csh = ...`

Comment: Yup the /etc/passwd was set to csh. Thanks